How to include an exclamation mark (!) in a URL with \href
I read the post Special character in \url where the suggested solution was to enter a \ symbol before special characters, however this does not appear to work when an exclamation mark (!) is in the URL.
\href{https://www.domain.ca/partwith\!inhere}{\ul{my_text}}

Using '!' does not work for me.

! Should work, what error did you get

use simply !,  https://www.domain.ca/partwith!inhere works fine.

Are you sure it's not the underscore character between "my" and "text" that's giving you grief?

Remove the \ from the url and just add the ! as it is:
\href{https://www.domain.ca/partwith!inhere}{\underline{my text}}

Was there a reason for removing the underscore character from the second argument of \href?

The _ is only allowed in latex math mode as a subscript command. So to use it in text, the proper command is \textunderscore. Or you can just use \_.

I suspect it's actually the underscore character in the second argument of \href that's causing the error. For sure, if I replace my_text with my\_text, I no longer encounter a problem.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex} \ifpdftex \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \fi
\usepackage{xurl} % allow line breaks in long URL strings in arbitrary locations
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % for '\href' macro

\begin{document}
\href{https://www.domain.ca/partwith!inhere}{my\_text}
\end{document}

